# How to add my Js/Css files to a Rails Application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a project which i was building in Sublime, with normal folders for Css and Js, where i have my scripts. When i create the project in Rails i only paste the content of body in the index.html.erb and my css and js files in the app/assets/stylesheets or app/assets/javascript, css works fine, except images console shows "Not found" (i dont know where to place my img folder to be found) and shows me that must load bootstrap first but i paste it all in my javascript folder.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Images can be places in `app/assets/images` and then you can use them in erb, css/scss, and js/coffee files if you append .erb to the filename you can use the asset helpers such as `asset_url` and so on. Also if you are using the `sass-rails` gem you can use the `asset-url` helper without needing to add the erb extension.